# Excel documents will open excel with blank window

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

When opening any excel document it will only bring up the excel window. To open the document I will have to goto file -> open.

I am using Office 2013 on windows 7 64bit

Only started happening the other day. What could be causing this?

The default application to open up .xls & .xlsx files is "EXCEL (DESKTOP)"

Comment: Could you check if you have Excel set up as Run as Administrator? This happend to me once and I think that was the reason.

Comment: Even after checking the box "Run as administrator" the issue still persists

Comment: Next time this happens, try pressing CTRL + F10 to see if this then shows the document?

Comment: Yeah I came across that earlier, unfortunately that checkbox is already unticked.

Comment: @Raystafarian Disabled all add ins, and Dave Rook, does not work

Comment: @Dave CTRL+F10 working for me, thanks a lot, you are saving my a lot of time everyday... by the way, because of some weird rules of stackoverflow(not able to vote comment again) I'm unable to vote-up your coment

Comment: @ShirishHerwade, I've moved it to my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Not sure exactly what is causing this. Could be a corrupted file or an update changed something. I found the following procedure on the Microsoft TechNet [forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a31c918b-cb7c-4008-b339-4f0fa6118ea9/excel-2013-will-not-open-file-using-double-click?forum=officeitpro). Give it a try.

1. Go to `Control Panel`
2. Choose `Uninstall Program` in `Program and Features`
3. Highlight your version of `Microsoft Office`
4. Click <kbd>change</kbd> button on the top
5. A pop up window will show up, select `Quick Repair`

If that doesn't work, check out [this support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211494). You didn't mention any error messages, but maybe the `Hot Fix` will resolve it.

Comment: Suggest [Microsoft KB2994633](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2994633): Excel: How to Troubleshoot Excel opening blank when you double-click a file icon or file name - is directly relevant

Answer (score 5):

If the page is a blank grey screen, but the document size is still appropriate for the file you were working on:

Click the View Tab
Click Unhide
Select the document
Click OK

Answer (score 2):

As per my comments, `try pressing CTRL + F10 to see if this then shows the document`

---

Click the Excel file, load up the empty Excel document and go to View -> Full Screen to see if then shows (<kbd>Escape</kbd> to exit). If it works, close and restart the same way and it should be OK again.

---

With Excel closed, click the 'start' button and in the search box, type

```
excel /unregserver
```

Close Excel.

Then, again, click start and type

```
excel /regserver
```

This should restore defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if you open the excel embedded in another app eg outlook and then try to open excel nothing loads, you see a blank excel.

For this scenario open the task manager and you may see one ore more Excel32.exe. Terminate all of them and reopen the document. It worked for me.

Comment: Did you ever discover what was going on to cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Excel Options > Advanced. Under General, is the box checked that says "Ignore Other Applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)? If so, uncheck it. That should fix the problem.